# Big Query - Convert INT to Date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, format

Can not find any solution to this:

Need to convert date(int) in the format - 20190101 to DATE in the format "2019-01-01"

I have tried:

- Cast(cast(20190101 AS STRING) AS date)
- FORMAT_DATE("%F",CAST(20190101 AS STRING))
- And so on...no success

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for `PARSE_DATE()`:

```
select PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(20190101 AS STRING))
```

Comment: FORMAT_DATE("%F",PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(20190101 AS STRING))) - Thank you

Answer (score 6):

if someone needs to convert the google analytics "int64 timestamp", I did this trick based on the answer above for this topic:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%s', CAST(TRUNC(event_timestamp/1000000) AS STRING))
```

Comment: Thank you @Júlio Filho! This is probably why many of us are here :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(20190101 AS STRING))
```